# Multi-process quicksort in python hangs for large numbers of elements

Tags: python, multiprocessing, quicksort

To learn a little more about processes in python I decided to implement quicksort using multiple processes. It seems to work fine on lists with fewer than ~21K elements but anything larger (say 25K elements) it just hangs.

I tried the `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(2**30)` trick to no avail. Is this simply because python doesn't like really deep recursions? Interestingly, the same algorithm works fine as a single process on a ~50k elements.

```
import random, multiprocessing, time

DESIRED_PROC_DEPTH = 2
proc_depth = 1 #start at one to count the parent process that kicks this all off

def main():
    import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(2**30)
    num_elements = 20000
    list_of_numbers = [random.randint(0,num_elements) for num in range(num_elements)]
    # print list_of_numbers
    simple_start = time.time()
    simple_sorted = simple_qs(list_of_numbers)
    simple_total_time = time.time() - simple_start
    print "Using a single thread we sorted " + str(num_elements) + " elements in " + str(simple_total_time) + " seconds"
    the_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    sorter = MTQuickSort(list_of_numbers, the_q)
    start = time.time()
    sorter.start()
    sorter.join()
    mt_total_time = time.time() - start
    sorted_list = the_q.get()
    # print sorted_list
    print "Sorted " + str(num_elements) + " elements in " + str(mt_total_time) + " seconds"


class MTQuickSort(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, list_to_sort, queue):
        super(MTQuickSort, self).__init__()
        print self.name
        self.queue = queue
        self.list = list_to_sort

    def run(self):
        self.queue.put(self.quicksort(self.list))

    def quicksort(self, list):
        global proc_depth
        global DESIRED_PROC_DEPTH
        if len(list) is 0:
            # base case is that list is empty
            return []
        else:
            pivot = list[0]
            less = [x for x in list[1:] if x <= pivot]
            greater = [x for x in list[1:] if x > pivot]
            if proc_depth < DESIRED_PROC_DEPTH:
                proc_depth += 1
                # We create threads in blocks of two since we partition the list into two parts
                lessor_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
                greater_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
                qs_process1 = MTQuickSort(less, lessor_q)
                qs_process2 = MTQuickSort(greater, greater_q)
                qs_process1.start()
                qs_process2.start()
                qs_process1.join()
                qs_process2.join()
                return lessor_q.get() + [pivot] + greater_q.get()
            else:
                less_than_pivot = self.quicksort(less)
                greater_than_pivot = self.quicksort(greater)
                return less_than_pivot + [pivot] + greater_than_pivot

def simple_qs(list):
    if len(list) is 0:
        # base case is that list is empty
        return []
    else:
        pivot = list[0]
        return simple_qs([x for x in list[1:] if x <= pivot]) + [pivot] + simple_qs([x for x in list[1:] if x > pivot])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Confirmed (on Linux): it generally works with 21900 elements and hangs with 21920 elements.  Why such precise numbers?  It's not related to sys.setrecursionlimit(), as the algorithm only recurses 10-20 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that you join() the subprocesses before you get() the result from the queues.  Apparently the queues don't eagerly read data from the subprocesses.  So when you call join(), the caller's process waits until the subprocess finishes, but the subprocess is itself waiting trying to send data to a pipe to its parent process.

If I move the various join() after the corresponding get(), it works.